# Cannot connect to mysql via Sequlize due to localhost resolving

Tags: sequelize.js, mysql2

I'm trying to connect to mysql like this:

```
new Sequelize('db', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
}
```

And I got this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1'
```

Yes, I don't have grants for `127.0.0.1`, only for `localhost`.

Why sequelize resolves `localhost` and try to connect by ip?  I don't want this behaviour, and I don't know how to fix it, without granting.

Any help would be appreciated

**UPD:** It's some sort of magic. Two computers resolves localhost to 127.0.0.1, but one don't. Source code and node_modules are the same. Node version is also the same
**UPD2** I wrote a simple script

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql', 'root', 'password', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: "localhost",
})
sequelize.authenticate()
```

And now I have two different outputs
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` and `Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)`

Comment: localhost's ip is 127.0.0.1

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I have same problem :(

Comment: I haven't resolved this problem a year ago. Never tried after it :(